# How do I assign the line number to each string present in a file

Tags: perl, line-numbers

**F1.txt**

```
tom a b c d e boy

bob a b c sun

harry a c d e girl
```

***result***

**F2.txt**

```
tom1 a1 b1 c1 d1 e1 boy1

tom2 a2 b2 c2 sun2

tom3 a3 c3 d3 e3 girl3
```

Hello everyone, I am quite new to Perl,can you kindly help me out with this new problem of mine. I have a file `F1.txt`, my job is to assign numbers after each string in a file according to its line number as shown in an example above. I have so far just managed to assign a number to each of the lines with this Perl one-liner

```
perl -pe '$_= ++$a." $_" if /./'
```

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit so that the answers given below actually answer the question that is asked. If you have a new question then then you ask it in a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe as follows:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\w)\b/$./g;'
```

Comment: Can you kindly help me out with the edited question that i have entered.Thanks in advance

Comment: @chinmoykhaund you should open a new question for that, although the solution will go along `perl -ne '@a=split/\s+/,$_;$t=shift @a; push @a,$t, print "@a\n"'`

Answer (score 2):

The special variable `$.` holds the current line number.

The regex `/(?<=\w)\b/g` matches each end of a word (or a number or underscore).
Or, more precise, a word boundary preceded by a "word" character which we don't include in our match. The `\b` assertion has zero width. Use the regex `s/(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)/$./g` to put a line number after each non-space sequence.

We can use the substitution operator `s///g` to append the line number in this way:

```
echo -e "a b\nc d" | perl -ne 's/(?<=\w)\b/$./g; print'
```

prints

```
a1 b1
c2 d2
```

Comment: Can you kindly help me out with one more problem

Answer (score 0):

in a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\w)\b/$./g' F1.txt >F2.txt
```